# Как изменить important стиль средствами javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Есть какой-либо элемент, к которому применили стиль с important:

```
element {
  property: value !important;
}
```

Могу ли я его изменить средствами javascript?

Пробовал вот так, но не получилось:

```
element.style.property = "new_value !important"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Самый короткий вариант

Используй `style.setProperty` для своего элемента, где 3-им параметром передается приоритет:

```
element.style.setProperty("property", "value", "important")
```

### Пример изменения цвета блока:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.changeStyle');
let block = document.querySelector('.testBlock');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  block.style.setProperty("background-color", "blue", "important")
})
```

```css
.testBlock {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="testBlock"></div>
<button class="changeStyle">Поменять цвет на синий</button>
```